# Stripe Xamarin. in app, Sign up and pay subscriptions plan, Can it be done?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, stripe-payments

I been working on a app where the common user can subscribe to different plans, which give different perks.

I been trying to do this by using Stripe's payment component from [xamarin component store](https://components.xamarin.com/view/stripe)

But for me, it seems like this component only give you the option to request a payment, but not subscript to a plan.

this leave me think, the only way i can make this happen, is to make the whole "payment and subscriptions to the plan" code on native IOS and Android, which i after [bind up against my PCL](http://Binding%20an%20iOS%20Objective-C%20Library)

So to conclude what i'm looking for is a more simple way to create this functionality,

Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the Xamarin extension should really only be used to collect the credit card details and "tokenize" the card.  The actual handling of the charge is done by your backend server (as described in the [documentation for the extension](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/stripe) under "Sending the token to your server").  Once you pass the otken to your backend, you can actually do anything you like with it-- including [attach it to a Customer Record](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) by setting the `source`-attribute when calling the Create a Customer API Endpoint.  Once you've created the Customer record, you can then [create a Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription) using your Plans.

Comment: I see. do you have any personal experience with this component for xamarin?